# Keep dividing array until every item is 1

Tags: javascript

I want to keep dividing a given array cm(arr) with this myArr [2,3,5,7] and store these values on another array (finalArr), I want to keep iterating until newArr items are 1

```
function cm(arr){

  let divide = [2,3,5,7];
  let finalArr = [];

 let newArr = arr.map(function(e){
    for(let i = 0; i < divide.length; i++){
      if(parseInt(e/divide[i]) === e/divide[i]){
        finalArr.push(divide[i])
        return e/divide[i]; 
      }   
    } 
  });

 let newFinal = new Set(finalArr)
  console.log([...newFinal])
  console.log(newArr)
  
}
```

```
cm([2,3,4,5,6])

[ 2, 3, 5 ] // the number that we divided each arr[item] with
[ 1, 1, 2, 1, 3 ] // the output of arr[item]/divide[item]


//desired output 

[2,3,5,2,3] // keep dividing arr[item] with divide[item] until the second array had all items = 1
[1,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: If the desired output is all 1s, then why not output immediately?

Comment: because I want to multiply all the numbers in final array to get the common multiple of 
the first array cm(arr)

Comment: That might be an essential information in the question: that you want to get the common multiple. Note that that is an algorithm that has been written down many times before. You can easily find it.

Comment: I actually wanted to create my own solution, so I didn't search for the actual answer, instead i wanted to implement what's in my head, but i think my this isn't always a good approach, because this will not work in bigger numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a loop and check if the array has all ones. This approacj works with a fallback for infinite loop with max ten loops.

```js
function cm(array) {
    const divide = [2, 3, 5, 7];
    let i = 10;

    while (i-- && !array.every(v => v === 1)) {
        const factors = [];
        array = array.map(v => {
            const d = divide.find(d => !(v % d));
            if (d === undefined) return v;
            if (!factors.includes(d)) factors.push(d);
            return v / d;
        });
        console.log('factors', ...factors)
        console.log('values', ...array)
    }
}

cm([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

Comment: thank you so much i could push the factors to a new array and get the common multiple

Answer (score 1):

```
function cm(arr) {
    let divide = [2, 3, 5, 7];
    return arr.map((item, i) => {
        let newItem = item;
        let divideItem = i in divide ? divide[i] : newItem;
        while (newItem > 1) {
            newItem /= divideItem;
            //one step for division
        }
        newItem = Math.ceil(newItem);
        return newItem;
    });
}
```